# How to make my Spawns in a Spawner Area2D's in Godot (C#)

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision, godot

I'm making a breakout game in Godot, I didn't want to manually add thousands of blocks/bricks on the screen, so I decided to make a Spawner.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccEiHSzvT8c) and instead of things like monsters I just added my bricks in there.
But I want to make my bricks collidable, since our player has to destroy the bricks, we should know when the ball collides with it. I do not want to make them just sprites.

I tried changing the sprite inside a Node2D as an Area2D instead, I also tried changing Node2D as an Area2D, I also tried making Position2D's (now called Marker2D's) as Area2D's. But nothing worked.

In any case, here's the code for the Spawner:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class Spawner : Node
{
    Group<string> blocks = new Group<string>() //* Our blocks red, blue, and green
    {
        {"res://red.tscn", 100 / 3},
        {"res://blue.tscn", 100 / 3},
        {"res://yellow.tscn", 100 / 3}
    };
    private int maxBlocks = 50; //* Maximum amount of blocks, so our game doesnt get filled with them infinitely
    private int currentBlocks = 0; //* The current amount of blocks in the game
    Group<string> results = new Group<string>(); //* The results of random block generating
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            string path = blocks.GetItem(); //* The path of our block
            PackedScene scene = ResourceLoader.Load(path) as PackedScene; //* Load our block as PackedScene
            Node2D block = scene.Instantiate() as Node2D; //* Instantiate as Area2D
            GetChild(i).AddChild(block); //* Add the block 
            block.Position = new Vector2(); //* Set its position
        }
    }
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {

    }
}
```

Code for the group:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Group<T> : Dictionary<T, double> where T : class
{
    public T GetItem()
    {
        double totalPercent = 100; //* The total percentage/weight of our items, in this case, 100
        double rand = new Random().NextDouble(); //* Generating a number from 0 to 1
        double totalVal = 0; //* The total value of our percentages/weight
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, double> kvp in this.ToList().OrderByDescending(v => v.Value))
        {
            totalVal += kvp.Value / totalPercent;
            if (rand <= totalVal) return kvp.Key; //* Return our item
        }
        return Keys.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Godot version: Godot 4.0 Mono.

Comment: You need to (additionally) add a [CollisionShape2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_collisionshape2d.html) node to the individual block

Comment: The Marker2D's, Node2Ds or the Sprites? like i said, i tried making each of them a Area2D, but nothing worked.

Comment: @George The `Area2D`, it needs a collider child, such as a `CollisionShape2D`. What exactly does "nothing worked" mean? - Anyway, why don't you use a `PhysicsBody2D` (such as an `StaticBody2D` or a `RigidBody2D` with `freeze` set to `true` and `freeze_mode` set to `FREEZE_MODE_STATIC`) for the bricks? Edit: just in case I'll also mention that the `PhysicsBody2D` also needs a collider.

Comment: I did add a collider when trying to make each of these nodes as Area2D's. Area2D didn't collide for some reason, even though I added a CollisionShape2D. I tried making Marker2D's as Area2D's, I tried making Node2D's as Area2D's, I tried making the sprites inside the Node2D's as Area2D's. But it didn't work, perhaps I have done something wrong but I don't remember.

Comment: The `Area2D` will detect other objects, but not constraint them, they don't stop, they don't bounce. So I wonder if what you observed is the `Area2D` working correctly.

Comment: So collision is detected, but other bodies aren't stopped? Alright.